# Accessing database credentials above the DocumentRoot

Tags: php, security, document-root

Is a 3rd party able to access files located about the DocumentRoot?

Document Root is `/var/www/website/public`
Database credentials are stored at `/var/www/website` in a php file

What security measures do I need to take to prevent 3rd party access?  Obviously someone could access by hacking into the server or compromising a user account.  Assuming those don't happen, is this secure?

Comment: What do you mean by third party?

Comment: For this example, anyone that isn't a developer or a sysadmin.

Comment: But … someone who still has access to the server? Or do you mean just access over HTTP via the web server? Be more specific.

Comment: Over HTTP via the the web server.  It is assumed the server accounts are secure and trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless users can run PHP or another server-side code on the server, yes, it's secure.